# Не работает код JQuery в Firefox

Tags: jquery

Код неправильно расчитывает высоту. Как быть?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    i = 0;
    $(".news-block-photo").each(function () {
        $(this).css({
            "height": $(".news-block:eq(" + i + ")").css("height")
        });
        i++;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: а зачем вы используете css() ? есть же height и outerheight... сделайте jsfiddle демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: да да вместо .css("height") просто height()

Comment: @fondyyy, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.